# How to keep a single Android instance of app in current running apps

Tags: android, guava, android-launcher

I have an android application which has two activities let's say A and B where A is the launcher activity. For activity A I registered an `intent-filter` which opens application for a specific URL. I want to have always a single task for my application in current running apps. To solve this problem I tried different combinations for `launchMode` attributes:

A `singleTop`, B `standard` but when I access app via intent URL I have two applications in current running apps

A `singleTask` B `standard` but every time when I open the app, it starts with activity A even the apps was already opened with activity B (in this case I want to resume the app)

A `singleTask` B `singleTask` the behavior is like A `singleTask` B `standard`

I want that my app to have the same behavior like for example gmail, always to have maximum one instance in current running apps, when I open it and there is already an instance in background, to resume it and if I open the app via intent filter I want to process the intent and provide content accordingly (for example gmail is in background and I receive a new mail notification after I click it, the android keep one instance for gmail and displays the new mail).

I use Samsung Galaxy Note 4 with Android 6.0

**Problem solved**

I found a solution for my problem, maybe it is not the best but it works. Firstly I added a new Activity to catch the `intent filter` which has `launchMode = "SingleTask"` and in its `onCreate` method I posted an event to kill all existing activities.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ("android.intent.action.VIEW".equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        // This Activity is started using an external app (eg: Gmail)
        // So start the app from the beginning 
        // (redirecting to Activity A)
        Intent mainIntent = getIntent(); // Copy the Intent used to launch me
        // Launch the real root Activity (launch Intent)
        mainIntent.setClass(this, StartActivity.class);

        // Post an event to kill all existing activities 
        // To do this i use Guava
        PubSub.getInstance().post(new KillActivityEvent());
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();

    } else {
        //  The activity wasn't started by an external app
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use fragment

Comment: The activity B is to big and fragments don't help me.